# Preserve empty text tags with pugixml

Tags: pugixml

I'm trying to use pugixml to modify xml configuration, created through boost::serialization and used by other application so i need to change only few fragments of document and leave all other parts the same.

Some nodes may store empty strings in the form of `<value></value>`. After load & save (with pugi) this nodes changes into `<value />`. After this boost::serialization cannot parse such file.

Load options `parse_ws_pcdata_single` and `parse_ws_pcdata` works only if there is white space between.

I didn't found saving option for saving empty nodes in form `<value></value>` too.

Is there any way to preserve opening & closing tags with zero text between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone still comes across this question, you don't need to change the source. Simply use this flag when writing your tree:

```
pugi::format_no_empty_element_tags
```

See the docs in https://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#saving.options

Answer (score 2):

There is no readily available option.

It is easy to change pugixml to output the XML that you need (probably easier than fixing boost::serialization...):

in pugixml.cpp around line 3249, there's this code:

```
        else if (!node.first_child())
            writer.write(' ', '/', '>', '\n');
```

Just remove these two lines if you're using indented formatting (if you're using format_raw there's similar code slightly above).

Comment: Yes, you're right. My collegue suggested the same. And if somebody use "raw" output there is one more place to fix: line 3235

Answer (score 2):

Pugixml has been updated and the answer to this has changed

This is for Pugixml version 1.6

To generate closing tags for all nodes,

***modify pugixml.cpp: line 3503***

from

```
PUGI__FN bool node_output_start(xml_buffered_writer& writer, xml_node_struct* node, unsigned int flags)
```

to

```
PUGI__FN void node_output_end(xml_buffered_writer& writer, xml_node_struct* node);
PUGI__FN bool node_output_start(xml_buffered_writer& writer, xml_node_struct* node, unsigned int flags)
```

***modify pugixml.cpp: line 3516***

from

```
writer.write(' ', '/', '>');
```

to

```
writer.write('>');
node_output_end(writer, node);
```